# How could I get a value out of a pandas DataFrame with a shape of (1,1) without using .to_list()[0]?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get a single value from a pandas DataFrame more efficiently.

This is how I do it now:

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# set up the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b'],'col2':[10,20,20],'col3':[100.0,200.0,300.0]})

# STEP 1 - filter down to a single row with loc
row_of_interest = df.loc[(df['col1'] == 'a') & (df['col2'] > 11)]

# STEP 2 - specify the column of interest
column_and_row_of_interest = row_of_interest['col3']

# STEP 3 - get the value out of dataframe format using to_list and list indexing
value_of_interest = column_and_row_of_interest.to_list()[0]
```

And of course, I can do steps 1-3 in a single line of code like this:

```
value_of_interest = df.loc[(df['col1'] == 'a') & (df['col2'] > 11)]['col3'].to_list()[0]
```

I imagine STEP 1 and STEP 2 might be unavoidable, but STEP 3 feels clunky. Is there a better way to get a value out of a DataFrame with a shape of (1,1) than using .to_list()[0] ?

Comment: https://trinket.io/python3/2cbd1ddbe9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```py
print(column_and_row_of_interest.squeeze())
```

OR:

```
print(column_and_row_of_interest.iat[0])
```

---

This prints:

```
200.0
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean `column_and_row_of_interest` instead of `value_of_interest`?

Comment: @e-motta Yes, that's more clear. Fixed :)

Comment: squeeze is simple, easy to remember, and appears to be intended for exactly the type of situation I am considering. I like the .iat and .iloc answers too.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `.iloc`

```
column_and_row_of_interest.iloc[0]
```

```
200.0
```